# In context of linux TCP system calls, what is an "incomplete connection request"?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, posix

The linux man page for `listen()` says:

> The behavior of the backlog argument on TCP sockets changed with Linux 2.2.  Now it speci‐
>          fies the queue length for **completely established sockets** waiting to be  accepted,  instead
>          of  the  number  of  **incomplete  connection requests**.  The maximum length of the queue for
>          incomplete sockets can be set using /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog.  When syncook‐
>          ies  are  enabled  there  is  no  logical maximum length and this setting is ignored.  See
>          tcp(7) for more information.

In this context, what is meant by "completely established sockets" vs. "incomplete connection requests"?

Comment: TCP requires a 3-way handshake before the connection is ready for communications. if the 3-way doesn't happen, it's an "incomplete connection". e.g. you went to shake someone's hand, slipped on a banana peel and broke your nose, forcing a trip to the hospital. that'd be an "incomplete handshake".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP protocol establishes connections with the so called three-way handshake, when host A initiates a connection to host B:

- A to B: SYN
- B to A: SYN + ACK
- A to B: ACK

An incomplete connection request is a connection for which a SYN has been sent, but the host has not received the SYN-ACK (either because the first or the second message, or their retrials, were lost).

This is different to the current semantics of the argument to `listen()`, "Completely established sockets", which specifies the number of connections already accepted by the TCP protocol, but not processed by the application (with an `accept()`), that can be queued before TCP ignores further connection requests.

Comment: This is on the server side - it would be a connection for which a SYN has been received and SYN+ACK sent, but ACK not received yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is in low level.

There is a point that open a connection, that is A side or A point.
And there is a listening point, or server point, that is a B point.

```
A send to B a SYN packet
B response to A a SYN ACK packet
Then A response is a ACK packet.
```

The connection is now established.

If there is a step that is not made, or the response is not ACK, the connection is not established.

Until the connection is established, the "connection" is in a list of "pending connections".

If the response is not an ACK, then the connection is cancelled and removed from the list of pending connections. obviously with an error.

But suppose that the last ACK is not send, but there is another new connection.
This pending connection is waitting a response and a new one connection is added to the list.
it keep in list until the response arrival, or reach a timeout.

The number of connection in the list is the "incomplete connection requests" and the number of successfully established connections is the "completely established sockets"